# Using exec to load module variables, using a file path

Tags: python

A textbook suggests I should be able to do this:

```
d = {}
exec("C://Users//Dave//Desktop//Bot//bot_config_data.py", globals(), d)
File "<string>", line 1   C://Users//Dave//Desktop//Bot//bot_config_data.py
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I can do this:

```
d = {}
exec('from bot_config_data import price_data', globals(), d)
```

But, I would like to do the former.

I'm trying to write a method which overrides config data from various files.

Am I completely off base here?

**Update**
The book was quite misleading. It posted part of the code, the result of the complete code block, and then gave the remainder. As I was referencing, rather than working through it cover to cover, I tripped over myself.

This is the code I now have:

```
data = {}
file = 'C:\\Users\\Dave\\Desktop\\Bot\\bot_config_data.py'
with open(file) as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), file, "exec")
    exec(code, globals(), data)
price_data = data["price_data"]
```

**Update2**
Using Mad Physicist's answer below, my code would be:

```
from importlib.util import spec_from_loader, module_from_spec
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

filepath = 'C:\\Users\\Dave\\Desktop\\Bot\\bot_config_data.py'
module_data = os.path.basename(filepath)
spec = spec_from_loader(module_data, SourceFileLoader(module_data, filepath))
bot_config_data = module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(bot_config_data)
price_data = bot_config_data.price_data
```

Comment: _"But, I would like to do the former."_ Why? What's wrong with the import statement?

Comment: @Aran-Fey. It's not a good way to do it, although using `exec` is the real problem here.

Comment: @Dave. I suspect that your textbook is not very good. Which one is it?

Comment: 'Mastering Object-orientated Programming' by Steven F.Lott. I suspect the mistake might be on my part. I'll double check.

Comment: I think you need to strip off the extension and you probably don't need anything more complicated than load_module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are completely off-base and the textbook is giving you some very bad advice.

[`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) runs Python code. As in Python statements, not the name of a file. From the docs:

> **exec**(*object*[, *globals*[, *locals*]])
>
> This function supports dynamic execution of Python code. *object* must be either a string or a code object. If it is a string, the string is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed (unless a syntax error occurs)

That is why your second statement works fine. If you want to run a Python module, import it. If you need to import using a dynamic name instead of a hard-coded `import` statement, you can use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module):

```
price_data = importlib.import_module('bot_config_data').price_data
```

This will run the whole import machinery for you, including ensuring that `bot_config_data` ends up in [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules).

If you really need something even fancier, you can use the [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) machinery. `__import__` is the under-the-hood implementation of the `import` statement:

```
d = {}
bot_config_data = __import__('bot_config_data', locals=d, from_list=['price_data'])
price_data = bot_config_data.price_data
```

If you want full control over the process, you can use the low-level machinery described here: [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67631/2988730). In particular see my answer to that question, since it describes how to load random text files as Python scripts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43602557/2988730:

```
from importlib.util import spec_from_loader, module_from_spec
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader 

spec = spec_from_loader("bot_config_data", SourceFileLoader("bot_config_data", "C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/Bot/bot_config_data.py"))
bot_config_data = module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(bot_config_data)
price_data = bot_config_data.price_data
```

Final note: It looks like you blindly converted all the `\\` to `//` in your path. Forward slashes do not need to be escaped, so you only need single forward slashes. If you want to avoid escaping your backslashes, put `r` in front of your string to make it a [raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/2988730).

Comment: The "bot_config_data" argument should be "bot_config_data.price_data".

Comment: @Dave. Where? `bot_config_data` is a module, `price_data` is an attribute of that module. You'll end up having to load the whole module even if you want just the one attribute anyway.

Comment: The arg to SourceFileLoader()? Otherwise, it throws an ImportError?

Comment: Fixed. There was an extra price_data in the spec

Answer (score 0):

> If you need to import using a dynamic name instead of a hard-coded
>   import statement, you can use importlib.import_module:
>
> `price_data = importlib.import_module('bot_config_data').price_data`

Huh? How is that "dynamic"? 'bot_config_data' is literally a string literal.

If you really want to import modules dynamically, contrary to what is widely believed, the only way to do this is with exec(). I challenge anyone to find or submit an example of importlib.import_module or __import__ being used to truly dynamically import modules.

**To be clear**: __import__ allows for the dynamic *handling* of imports, which is not the same as dynamically importing, as that is a chicken/egg type problem only exec() can solve.

The problem is that importlib.import_module() returns an object, which needs an assignment. (It doesn't just add to the global namespace as is often implied.) But you can't use the same argument on both sides of the assignment. So while it allows you to do handle imports in a more dynamic way, it provides no way of dynamically importing modules.