# Why use importlib over exec import

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, exec, python-importlib

In Python, if you want to dynamically import a module (such as from a string name) you can use the module `importlib` and the function `importlib.import_module("foo")`, which essentially gives the same result as `import foo` (but it's dynamic).

Anyway, in my program, I'm using a function to import a module from a list, so it looks something like this:

```
# Note: this code does not produce the desired result.
# Please see the snippet below, for the working version
module_list = ["os"]

def import_module(name):
    exec("global {}".format(name))
    exec("import {}".format(name))
for item in module_list:
    import_module(item)
```

I haven't seen this type of solution anywhere else on the web. What I'm asking, is why? Is it bad practice because I'm using the `exec()` function (as I've read not to do countless times) or is it because It's simply more confusing

*Edit: I feel like it's relevant to note that it's not my exact code above, but it's the part that's actually relevant to this question, instead of confusing people*

*Edit (2): thanks to user Aran-Fey for discovering that my code doesn't work. I hadn't properly tested this specific snippet. Here's a version that works in python 3.6:*

```
module_list = ["os"]

def import_module(name):
    exec("global {}".format(name), globals())
    exec("import {}".format(name), globals())

for item in module_list:
    import_module(item)
```

Comment: For one reason, generally you want to avoid re-inventing the wheel. So I guess for the same reason you don't use `def my_print(x): sys.stdout.write(x+'\n')`

Comment: For one thing, it's easier to spot mistakes in your code when you use importlib... Did you notice that your `exec` code doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe you found this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012761/using-exec-to-load-module-variables-using-a-file-path

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks for pointing that out. I'm gonna be quite honest, and admit that I kinda just made that code up for the example. It works in my original code and I have absolutely no intention of trying to find out why it does. Hopefully you still get the point I'm making.